# Prove that $(a_1 − 1)(a_2 − 2)...(a_9 − 9)$ is always an even number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

$a_1, a_2,..., a_9$ is an arbitrary permutation of positive integers from 1 to 9. Prove that $(a_1 − 1)(a_2 − 2)...(a_9 − 9)$ is always an even number.

So I don't understand what the question is asking by "arbitrary permutation of positive integers". Does that mean consecutive integers or multiples? And also, can someone please help me prove this too? Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Among the numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_9$ each of the number $1,2,\dots,9$ will occur exactly once each in some arbitrary order.  So, it is asking you to prove that for instance $(1-1)(2-2)(3-3)\cdots (9-9)$ is even.  It is also asking you to prove that $(9-1)(8-2)(7-3)\cdots (1-9)$ is even and $(2-1)(3-2)(4-3)(5-4)\cdots (9-8)(1-9)$ is even and all other several hundred thousand possible ways in which the numbers $1,2,\dots,9$ may be assigned to $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_9$.  Clearly, you won't succeed by checking each of the several hundred thousand cases manually so a better argument is needed.

Comment: "Arbitrary permutation" means you  an arrange the digits from $1$ to $9$ in any order.

Comment: There are only four even numbers from $1$ to $9$, so at least one of $a_1, a_3, a_5, a_7$, and $a_9$ has to be odd, so at least one of $a_1-1, a_3-3, a_5-5, a_7-7, $ and $a_9-9$ has to be even, so the product is even

Answer (score 8):

Observe that
$$\sum_{i=1}^9 (a_i - i) = 0$$
Thus, the sum of an odd number of terms is $0$, so there exists at least one even term in this sum. Hence,
$$2 \mid \prod_{i=1}^9 (a_i - i).$$

Comment: wow, great solution!

Answer (score 3):

There are only four even numbers from $1$ to $9$, so at least one of $a_1, a_3, a_5, a_7$, and $a_9$ has to be odd, so at least one of $a_1-1, a_3-3, a_5-5, a_7-7, $ and $a_9-9$ has to be even, so the product is even.

Answer (score 2):

The only way the product $(a_1 − 1)(a_2 − 2) \dots (a_9 − 9)$ could be odd is if $a_1, a_3, a_5, a_7$, and $a_9$ are all even numbers. That would take $5$ even numbers ...